# Compute frequency of sinusoidal signal, c++

Tags: c++, signals

i have a sinusoidal-like shaped signal,and i would like to compute the frequency.
I tried to implement something but looks very difficult, any idea?
So far i have a vector with timestep and value, how can i get the frequency from this?
thank you

Comment: I would suggest reading about the [formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sine_wave) to find frequency of a Sine wave.

Comment: I'd be tempted to collect all the times the value crosses zero and work from there.

Comment: Use the Fourier transform.

Answer (score 4):

If the input signal is a perfect sinusoid, you can calculate the frequency using the time between positive 0 crossings. Find 2 consecutive instances where the signal goes from negative to positive and measure the time between, then invert this number to convert from period to frequency. Note this is only as accurate as your sample interval and it does not account for any potential aliasing.

Comment: For a more accurate result use many zero crossings and take the number of crossings over the number of samples, times the frequency of the samples.

Answer (score 2):

You could try auto correlating the signal. An auto correlation can be rapidly calculated by following these steps:

1. Perform FFT of the audio.
2. Multiply each complex value with its complex conjugate.
3. Perform the inverse FFT of the audio.

The left most peak will always be the highest (as the signal always correlates best with itself).  The second highest peak, however, can be used to calculate the sinusoid's frequency.

For example if the second peak occurs at an offset (lag) of 50 points and the sample rate is 16kHz and the window is 1 second then the end frequency is 16000 / 50 or 320Hz.  You can even use interpolation to get a more accurate estimation of the peak position and thus a more accurate sinusoid frequency.  This method is quite intense but is very good for estimating the frequency after significant amounts of noise have been added!